# Summing the boolean attributes of a list of objects in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, performance, sum

I have a list of python objects which have a boolean attribute. I wish to sum these booleans (i.e. count how many are true) in a relatively performant way. My test script looks something like:

```
import random
import timeit

class testClass:
    def __init__(self, boolean):
        self.bool = bool(boolean)

bools = [random.randint(0,1) for i in range(1000)]

class_instances = [testClass(boolean=bool) for bool in bools]
```

I now have a list of 1000 class instances whose bool attribute is a boolean

Clearly the canonical thing to do, that I've seen elsewhere, is something like:

`sum([instance.bool for instance in class_instances])`

or even

`sum(instance.bool for instance in class_instances)` (slower apparently)

However, this operation is going to happen a lot, and taking a peek at the profiling seems to suggest that I'm wasting time creating a list just to sum over it (or constructing a generator?) - assigning the list ahead of time and then summing makes the "summation" step much quicker:

`bool_list = [instance.bool for instance in class_instances]`

and then `sum(bool_list)` is fast BUT bool_list obviously doesn't update if an object in the original class_instances is mutated - pass by assignment yada yada.

Is there something I should be thinking about that I haven't? Along with many others I think list comprehensions are pretty much the best thing since sliced bread, but I'd kill for an array of pointers in this context. I suspect my best bet is re-implementing my class as a "larger" class, in the sense of containing more data i.e. a class with list attributes as opposed to constructing lists of class attributes.

Comment: You could maintain a total sum as a class attribute on `testClass`. Then implement `.bool` as a property with getter and setter, where you can update the total on any mutation.

Comment: I like this, thanks! I think as I'm also updating the boolean quite frequently this might not be better, as the setting of all the attributes in the list is currently taking just under 3x as long as the summing in the slow case. I suppose it would be better if I was summing more than 3x as often as setting - I'll have a think about that for my code.

Comment: In my suggestion, you would not have to sum at all

Comment: when I say 'summing' I mean retrieving the sum, via whatever means. It looks like the code does set quite a lot less than it retrieves the sum typically, so hopefully this will give a bit of a speedup!

Comment: @condimentman Do you need to have just one `class_instances`. You can have 2 lists, `true_class_instances`, `false_class_instances` and and if you want to get sum just do `len(true_class_instances)`

Comment: @AndrejKesely the logic that updates the `realClass.boolean` are implemented in methods of `realClass`, so `class_instances` and similar aren't in the scope, but worth considering in the inevitable rewrite ;).

Comment: @user2390182 I had a play with this. It worked quite nicely but I had a couple of issues (only due to lack of more detail in the original post): 1. Doesn't play well with concurrency, with all the Threads in a `ThreadPoolExecutor.Pool()` adding to the same total. 2. Resetting has to be done explicitly before repetition. Neither of these work particularly well for my usecase but I'll keep playing around.

Comment: @user2390182 In the meantime I'm just passing each `realClass` instance a dict on initialization instead of using class attributes

Answer (score 0):

Following user2390182 comments, you could keep a `total_count` as a class attribute of your `TestClass`.

Here's an example. I also renamed your `bool` attribute to `bool_` to avoid using a python keywor

```py
class TestClass:
    total_count = 0

    def __init__(self, bool_):
        self.bool_ = bool_

    @property
    def bool_(self):
        return self._bool_

    @bool_.setter
    def bool_(self, value):
        bool_value = bool(value)
        if hasattr(self, "_bool_"):
            if bool_value and not self._bool_:
                TestClass.total_count += 1
            elif not bool_value and self._bool_:
                TestClass.total_count -= 1
        else:
            if bool_value:
                TestClass.total_count += 1
        self._bool_ = bool_value

bools = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(1000)]
class_instances = [TestClass(bool_=bool_) for bool_ in bools]
print(sum(bools))
print(TestClass.total_count)  # TestClass.total_count == sum(bools)
```

I'm not sure how to deal with deletion though. This seems to work.

```
class TestClass:
    ...

    @bool_.deleter
    def bool_(self):
        if self._bool_:
            TestClass.total_count -= 1
        del self._bool_ 

    def __del__(self):
        if self._bool_:
            TestClass.total_count -= 1

bools = [random.randint(0, 1) for i in range(1000)]
class_instances = [TestClass(bool_=bool_) for bool_ in bools]
print(sum(bools))
print(TestClass.total_count)  # TestClass.total_count == sum(bools)
class_instances = class_instances[:500]
bools = bools[:500]
print(sum(bools))
print(TestClass.total_count)  # TestClass.total_count == sum(bools)

new_instance = TestClass(bool_=True)
print(TestClass.total_count)
del new_instance
print(TestClass.total_count)
```

Comment: Yep that's pretty much what I came up with too, though for brevity: testClass.total += value - self._bool_ to avoid the ugly ifs and elifs